# Get List of Cards based on Board - Trello API

Tags: api, trello

I am trying to return a list of cards based on the board a user chooses from a dropdown select menu.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/nNesx/1378/

I have Created the list of boards as follows

```
var $boards = $("<select>")
        .text("Loading Boards...")
        .appendTo("#output");

    // Output a list of all of the boards that the member 
    // is assigned to
    Trello.get("members/me/boards", function(boards) {
        $boards.empty();
        $.each(boards, function(ix, board) {
            $("<option>")
            .attr({href: board.url, target: "trello"})
            .addClass("board")
            .text(board.name)
            .appendTo($boards);
        });  
    });
```

which gives me a dropdown select of all boards available.

Once the user chooses the board I then want them to see the cards for that board. I am using this code for cards, but all cards just appear.

```
var $cards = $("<div>")
        .text("Loading Boards...")
        .appendTo("#outputCards");

    // Output a list of all of the boards that the member 
    // is assigned to based on what they choose in select dropdown
    Trello.get("members/me/cards", function(cards) {
        $cards.empty();
        $.each(cards, function(ix, card) {
            $("<a>")
            .attr({href: card.url, target: "trello"})
            .addClass("card")
            .text(card.name)
            .appendTo($cards);
        });  
    });
```

I am not sure how to display the cards based on the select drop-down?

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/nNesx/1378/

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a different resource

Instead of using `members/me/cards`, use `boards/[board_id]/cards`

Just add an ID to your select and the board id to each option...

```
var $boards = $("<select>")
        .attr("id", "boards") /* we'll use this later */
        .text("Loading Boards...")
        .appendTo("#output");

     $("<option>")
      /* notice the added board id value */
      .attr({href: board.url, target: "trello", value : board.id})
      .addClass("board")
      .text(board.name)
      .appendTo($boards);
```

And then you can grab all cards for just that board

```
var resource = "boards/" . $("#boards").val() . "/cards";
Trello.get(resource, function(cards) {
  // rest of code...
});
```